# Rails - ActiveRecord Dirty - Getting associated objects from the changes hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an audit trail of sorts for an app so that the user can see what is being changed throughout the system.

I have a hash of changes from ActiveRecord Dirty, like follows:

```
{"ingredient_type_id"=>[nil, 199575006], "name"=>[nil, "asdfg"], "amount"=>[nil, 3.0], "unit"=>[nil, "x"], "notes"=>[nil, "asdf"]}
```

This works great and I can parse what I need to output and create database records with the info.

I just have one question - How can I get associated objects from this? In this case, the ingredient_type? I actually want to output something like:

"Ingredient type was changed to #{IngredientType.find(199575006).name}."

But I'm not sure how I would parse that hash on a dynamic basis to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the way you've suggested I'd have thought, But you don't need to parse the hash for the changes, Dirty gives you much more than that

```
if ingredient_type_id_changed?
  unless ingredient_type_id.blank?
    ingredient_name = IngredientType.find(ingredient_type_id).name        
  else
    ingredient_name = 'blank'        
  end
end
```

You might even be able to do `ingredient_type.name`, Not sure at that point if active record dirty will let you go through the association.  If you test it (or if anyone else knows)  let me know